# How to restrict current_user to confirmed users only in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am still new to Rails and I would like to adjust the following (fairly standard) code so that any `current_user` is required to have their `confirmed` database field set to `true`. In other words, if a `user`'s `confirmed` database field is `false` he should not be able to become a `current_user`.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end  

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_token(cookies[:token]) if cookies[:token]
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

end
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def current_user
  user = User.find_by_token(cookies[:token]) if @current_user.nil? && cookies[:token]
  @current_user ||= user if user && user.confirmed 
end
```